# How to get list of all bookmark-elements from a Word document to an array in order by location: VBA / Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to fetch all the bookmarks in my Word document, and then push them to an array. The bookmarks must be sorted by their location in document not by name.

ex. here's a list of bookmarks in a document,

```
[bm_s]  (header)
[bm_h]  (title)
[bm_a]  (footer)
```

I want the bookmarks to keep their order so that the array will look like as following,

```
array {bm_s, bm_h, bm_a, }
```

ex. how it should not look like below,

```
array {bm_a, bm_h, bm_s, }
```

I got the fetching of all the bookmarks from document working. I get all the bookmarks in random order when fetching and pushing to the array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oki, so i figured it out,

Here's how its done if someone else is interested in fetching all of the bookmarks with respect to its location on document.

```
Dim objDoc As Document
Set objDoc = ActiveDocument

For i = 1 To objDoc.Bookmarks.Count
Debug.Print objDoc.Range.Bookmarks(i) 'here you can change the code to push the bookmarks in an array
Next i
```

Comment: Oki, so i think i might have jumped to conclusion too early, this code does in fact fetch every bookmark in document, but except for the bookmarks in the headers and footers.

Comment: What an elegant solution, thank you. I was on the verge of writing something to loop through the bookmarks comparing the start/end character indexes and sorting them by that. Saved me an hour of hacky awful work.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone still wants to know; you can access different parts of a MS Word document, like this:

```
ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory).Bookmarks.Count
ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Bookmarks.Count
ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryFooterStory).Bookmarks.Count
```