# Sorting word bookmarks by location in vba

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

I am trying to cycle through the bookmarks in a word document by their location.

yes I have seen this: [How to get list of all bookmark-elements from a Word document to an array in order by location: VBA / Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725395/get-all-bookmark-elements-from-a-word-document-to-an-array-in-sorted-order-vba)

no it didn't work. and for the life of me I am not sure why this doesn't since it is lifted from a MS support page.

```
Sub cycleBookmarks()
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.DefaultSorting = wdSortByLocation
 Dim bkm As Bookmark
  For Each bkm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
  Next bkm
End Sub
```

Anybody know how to properly cycle through bookmarks by document location? I don't care about headers and footers (though a complete answer would be nice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff822387%28v=office.14%29.aspx) `DefaultSorting property`:

> Returns or sets the sorting option for bookmark names displayed in the
>   Bookmark dialog box (Insert menu). Read/write WdBookmarkSortBy.

Therefore you need to use @Mana solution from the link you provided in your question.

Comment: looks like I forgot to grab the range of the bookmark when I implelemented the solution the first time. Thanks for the help.