# Iterating bookmarks adds them in reverse order, and I'm not seeing why

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a couple of quick macros, one to mark text as a project and bookmark it, and another to gather all the bookmarks in an index. When inserting the new text (switch hyperlinks back to the bookmark) the new paragraph is ahead of the last paragraph(s) and reverses the order.

What am I missing here?

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Project_Bookmarks_TOC"
Option Explicit
Const Prj As String = "PROJECT_"

Private Sub Bookmark_Generate_List()
    Dim bkm As BookMark
    Dim newParagraph As Range
    Dim documentEnd As Range
    Dim strOut As String
    
    ' Create a new Range object at the end of the document
    Set documentEnd = ActiveDocument.Range
    documentEnd.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

    For Each bkm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        If Left(LCase(Trim(bkm.Name)), Len(Prj)) = LCase(Prj) Then
            ' Create a new paragraph for each bookmark
            Set newParagraph = documentEnd.Duplicate
            newParagraph.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            newParagraph.Text = bkm.Name & vbTab & bkm.Range & vbTab & bkm.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) & vbCr

            ' Add hyperlink to the bookmark
            ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=newParagraph, _
                Address:="", _
                SubAddress:=bkm.Name, _
                TextToDisplay:=bkm.Name & vbTab & bkm.Range & vbTab & bkm.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) & vbCr

            ' Move the cursor to the end of the document
            newParagraph.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End If
    Next bkm
    
    ' Format the last paragraph as needed
    With newParagraph.ParagraphFormat
        .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft ' Set alignment to left
        ' Add more formatting options as needed
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried Indexes and TOCs and everything else but the format was awkward and this seems to work. If I could get it to behave like the TOC that would be ideal - but I'll settle for the right order to start.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Try iterating in reverse order, counting down from Bookmarks.Count rather than up to it. You may well be overwriting/deleting bookmarks. See Working With Bookmarks in VBA on the Word MVP FAQ: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/WorkWithBookmarks.htm *(I have not worked through your code, but this is a common problem with vba and the bookmarks collection.)*

Comment: @taller - Where words are phrases are tagged A, B, C, D, it generates output as D, C, B, A instead of the anticipated A B C D... I figure it is something in the iteration of the bookmarks, I want to write it to the document like a TOC as A B C D.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Bingo! and :facepalm: didn't realize it was the bookmark sequence throwing it.

Comment: @Apsis0215 You could get it as A B C D with `For Each` iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Bookmark_Generate_List1()
    Dim bkm As Bookmark
    Dim newParagraph As Range
    Dim documentEnd As Range
    Dim strOut As String
    Const Prj As String = "BK" ' modify as needed
    Selection.EndKey Word.wdStory
    If Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start <> Selection.End Then
        Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
    Dim iStart: iStart = Selection.Start
    For Each bkm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        If Left(LCase(Trim(bkm.Name)), Len(Prj)) = LCase(Prj) Then
            ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=Selection.Range, _
                Address:="", _
                SubAddress:=bkm.Name, _
                TextToDisplay:=bkm.Name & vbTab & bkm.Range & _
                vbTab & bkm.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) & vbCr
            Selection.Move wdParagraph, 1
        End If
    Next bkm
    With ActiveDocument.Range(iStart, Selection.End).ParagraphFormat
        .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation:

> [Bookmark order for] the `Document` object, the index number represents the position of the bookmark in the **alphabetical list of bookmarks in the Bookmarks dialog** box [...]

> [Bookmark order for] `Selection` or `Range` object [...] index number represents **the position of the bookmark**

Take the following example:
[image]

Using your code, it will return: `ABookmark`, `DBookmark`, `ZBookmark`.

```vb
    For Each bkm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        MsgBox "Doc: " & bkm
    Next bkm
```

Using a range in the document instead, it will return `ZBookmark`, `ABookmark`, `DBookmark`

```vb
    For Each bkm In ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0).Bookmarks
        MsgBox "Range: " & bkm
    Next bkm
```

There's supposed to be an API `wdSortByLocation` for this, but like [this question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23538730/3196753) -- as well as my testing -- `wdSortByLocation` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Good point but my initial routine tags: "PROJECT_0020 [PROJECT_0020" for consistency, so the numeric should sort in order PROJECT_0020...21...22...etc.

Comment: @Apsis0215 gotcha.  So is the issue related to bookmarks in paragraphs specifically?  If so, I think the accepted answer doesn't clearly explain this (instead the comments must be read to infer this, which will make it harder for others suffering the same problem to understand).

Answer (score 0):

@charles Kenyon's solution worked - @Taller answered the original question with Word's mysterious inversion of the paragraphs and solved the order issue on output which is what I was trying to grasp. (Thanks!)

Here is the revised code based on Keynyons solution, original for look for bookmarks reversed.

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Project_Bookmarks_TOC"
Option Explicit
Const Prj As String = "PROJECT_"

Private Sub Bookmark_Generate_List()
    Dim bkm As BookMark
    Dim newParagraph As Range
    Dim documentEnd As Range
    Dim strOut As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Create a new Range object at the end of the document
    Set documentEnd = ActiveDocument.Range
    documentEnd.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

    ''For Each bkm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    For i = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set bkm = Nothing: Set bkm = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(i)
        If Left(LCase(Trim(bkm.Name)), Len(Prj)) = LCase(Prj) Then
            ' Create a new paragraph for each bookmark
            Set newParagraph = documentEnd.Duplicate
            newParagraph.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            newParagraph.Text = bkm.Name & vbTab & bkm.Range & vbTab & bkm.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) & vbCr

            ' Add hyperlink to the bookmark
            ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=newParagraph, _
                Address:="", _
                SubAddress:=bkm.Name, _
                TextToDisplay:=bkm.Name & vbTab & bkm.Range & vbTab & bkm.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) & vbCr

            ' Move the cursor to the end of the document
            newParagraph.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End If
    Next i
    ''Next bkm
    
    ' Format the last paragraph as needed
    With newParagraph.ParagraphFormat
        .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft ' Set alignment to left
        ' Add more formatting options as needed
    End With

End Sub

Sub BookmarkQuickBasic()
Dim bkm As BookMark
Dim BKmCt As Integer
Dim i As Integer

    If Selection.Range = "" Then
        MsgBox "Select some text to bookmark first", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each bkm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        ''get value, reassign number if it doesn't match index??? -recreate bookmark list
        If Left(LCase(Trim(bkm.Name)), Len(Prj)) = LCase(Prj) Then
            If BKmCt < Val(Right(bkm.Name, 4)) Then    ''get highest count
                BKmCt = Val(Right(bkm.Name, 4))
            End If
        End If
    Next bkm

    BKmCt = BKmCt + 1
    
    Selection.Text = "[" & Prj & Format(BKmCt, "0000") & " | " & Selection.Text
       
    For i = Len(Selection.Text) To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(Selection.Text, i, 1) >= Chr(32) Then
            Selection.Text = Left(Selection.Text, i) & "]" & Right(Selection.Text, Len(Selection.Text) - i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    Selection.Style = "Project Candidate"
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        .Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:=Prj & Format(BKmCt, "0000")
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByLocation
        .ShowHidden = False
    End With
End Sub

'''--------field bookmarks
Private Sub BookmarkQuickAndCreateField()
    Dim selectedText As String
    Dim bookmarkName As String
    Dim formField As formField
    Dim bkm As BookMark
    Dim BKmCt As Integer
    
    If MsgBox("Warning, this will wipeout Hyperkiks and formatting to push selected text  into fields for project bookmarks." & vbCr & vbCr & "Continue?", vbCritical + vbOKCancel) <> vbOK Then Exit Sub
   
    For Each bkm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        ''get value, reassign number if it doesn't match index??? -recreate bookmark list
        If Left(LCase(Trim(bkm.Name)), Len(Prj)) = LCase(Prj) Then
            If BKmCt < Val(Right(bkm.Name, 4)) Then    ''get highest count
                BKmCt = Val(Right(bkm.Name, 4))
            End If
        End If
    Next bkm

    BKmCt = BKmCt + 1
    
    ' Check if there is a selection
    If Selection.Type = wdSelectionNormal Then
        ' Get the selected text
        selectedText = Selection.Range.Text
        ' Define the bookmark name
        bookmarkName = Prj & Format(BKmCt, "0000") ' Replace with the actual bookmark name


        ' Add a bookmark using the selected text
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:=bookmarkName

        ' Create a form field linked to the bookmark
        Set formField = ActiveDocument.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput)
        formField.Name = bookmarkName
        formField.Result = selectedText ' Set default text using Result property
        formField.TextInput.EditType Type:=wdRegularText, Default:=selectedText, Format:=""
        
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select some text before running this macro.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```